# Eclipse plug-in that keeps track of the most recent functions and/or variables used, and gave a keyboard shortcuts to access them

Tags: eclipse

I am looking for a Eclipse plug-in that keeps track of the most recent functions and/or variables used, and gave keyboard shortcuts to access them.

For example, it could display the list of functions and/or variables recently used, and gives keyboard shortcuts to paste them, in a similar fashion as a clipboard manager:

[image]

I'm more interested in variables than in functions.